# Silent YouTube Video Before It Plays

Tags: javascript, html, webview, javafx-webengine

I created a very simple `WebView` Browser that will open a `YouTube` Video directly from some `URL`, say: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=someId

All I want is to **mute** this video by default or *before* playing (i.e. once it's loaded).

What I tried is:

```
String muteScript = "window.onload = function() {\n" + 
                    "var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video'),\n" +
                    "audios = document.querySelectorAll('listen');\n" +
                    "[].forEach.call(videos, function(video) { video.muted = true; });\n" +
                    "[].forEach.call(audios, function(audio) { audio.muted = true; })}";

WebView browser = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oS, Worker.State nS) {
               if (nS == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                   webEngine.executeScript(muteScript);
               }
        }});
```

The problem is, the video sound is playing a ***bit*** then stops.

Is there a way to mute it ***before*** it plays?

---

**Update**

I am still trying to find a working solution but it seems almost impossible.
Somehow, even changing each video's attribute `defaultMuted = true;` does not have any effect.

It's worth mentioning that I could not by any mean mute the video unless it strictly plays a bit (*back to square one!*).. that's why my following workaround failed at the last step:

1. Convert the YouTube URL to Embedded and set `autoplay=0`.
2. Change all videos' `muted` attributes to `true`.
3. Play the video by performing a `click()` on it pragmatically!

**Result**: *No Effect*.

Also I tried to trigger an event `onwaiting` at the beginning of the video to mute it after. But as I mentioned, `muted = true;` attribute seems to strictly mute the video **while** it's playing or at least **played** a bit even if it's paused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was attempting to hack the cookies of the `WebView` and find if I can make the Video `muted` similar to the other popular browsers when they remember the user's previous session preference.

From there, I found out how to embed a YouTube Video with sound muted and that is by simply adding `mute=1` to the video URL!!

The approach is as follows:

1. Get the Video URL.
2. Convert it to Embedded.
3. Add `autoplay=1&mute=1` to the end of the URL.

**Done!**

```
String convertToEmbed(String url) {
    String pattern = "(?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/|youtu.be\\/|\\/v\\/|\\/e\\/|watch\\?v%3D|watch\\?feature=player_embedded&v=|%2Fvideos%2F|embed%\u200C\u200B2F|youtu.be%2F|%2Fv%2F)[^#\\&\\?\\n]*";
    Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(url);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + matcher.group() + "?autoplay=1&mute=1";
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try HTML DOM Muted Property ?

```
var vid = document.getElementById("videoElementId");
vid.muted = true;
```

i think above code will help you. or else refer this below link
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_muted

Comment: `video` is the type of the element, not its id.

Comment: i mentioned that element id as video just for example dude.

Comment: I tried this from the beginning and mentioned it in my question!